# Colação com problemas no Localhost

Tags: php, utf-8

A um 1 atraz fiz um banco com colação latin1_swedish_ci e charset latin1,

O html ficou charset `UTF-8` na Index que emgloba todas páginas dentro em html,

E o php ficou UTF-8 com os códigos por página:

```
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
```

E no conexão.php está:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
setlocale(LC_ALL,"pt_BR");
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

$db_servidor="localhost";
$db_usuario="XXXX";
$db_senha="XXXX";
$meubanquinho="XXXX";

$conexao = new mysqli($db_servidor, $db_usuario, $db_senha, $meubanquinho);
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {trigger_error(mysqli_connect_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');
}
?>
```

Tudo no localhost funcionando certinho,

Quando exportei o banco para Kinghost

Tudo funcionando certinho também,

Hoje, depois de 1 ano, importo o banco para o notebook e a página aberta no localhost, está recebendo os dados do banco e exibindo desconfigurado.

Mas o que recebe do banco, está desconfigurado, está vindo o que realmente está no banco

Lá no banco, está desconfigurado também,

**Se eu enviar meu nome "André" pela página, está salvando "André"**

**Mas os registros anteriores, importados, estão incorretos, o nome:**

**LetÃ­cia Martins**

**Está no banco desta forma, e quando recebo na minha página localhost, está recebendo:**

**LetÃ­cia Martins**

Pelo que vi, lá no host, está salvando errado,

Na hora de enviar a palavra UTF-8 recebida no html/php, ele manda em UTF-8, até por que na página de salvar tem o código:

```
ini_set('default_charset','UTF-8');
```

Chega no banco e fica errado, ele reconhece o latin1,

Se no banco ficar latin1, e eu abrir aqui no localhost meu nome "André"

Tudo bem,

Mas ele abre errado, exibe errado, ele tenta exibir em UTF-8,

Eu não entendo por que antes funcionava no localhost, e agora, após formatação e muito tempo, não,

E tambem não entendo por que o mesmo banco, e os mesmos arquivos da hospedagem, estão no meu pc, e lá funciona, e aqui não.

É alguma configuraçao ?

Algum código que não funciona aqui no localhost e está funcionando lá ?

EDITADO

```
Resolução Temporária:
```

> Gente, me passaram para dar um decode assim:
>   echo utf8_decode($variavel_do_banco);
>   no dado que vem do banco, e deu
>   certo, acontece que agora 90% tá resolvido,
>   eu queria um codigo tipo
>   aquele la de cima as linhas finais do eu conexao.php
>   era para converter tudo automatico na impressao, e não está funcionando, tem algum que faça isso para substituir e funcionar sem usar o decode em cada echo ?

Tentei os codigos a baixo e não funcionou:

```
$charset = "utf8";
mysqli_set_charset ( $conexao , $charset );
$conexao->set_charset("utf8");
$conexao->query("SET character_set_connection = utf8"); 
$conexao->query("SET character_set_client = utf8"); 
$conexao->query("SET character_set_results = utf8");
$conexao->query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8';");
$conexao->query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Li a respeito em:

http://kunststube.net/frontback/

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?287107-Encoding-while-inserting-in-mysql

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829816/php-set-character-names-using-mysqli

Comment: header ("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: Isso já tem, não é o problema.

Comment: `ini_set` define a codificação para funções de conversão de caracteres - **htmlentities, htmlspecialchars, etc**. Podes experimentar `print ini_get('default_charset');`, veja [isto](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=29983)